# OnVif authentication failed for Milesight camera

Tags: soap, camera, elixir, onvif, elixir-iex

I have 2 Milesight PTZ cameras and 5 Hikvision PTZ cameras. I use OnVif commands to move the camera (left, right, up, down). I wrote a code in the Elixir to send these OnVif commands to the cameras.

**My Code**

```
def request(%{"auth" => auth, "url" => base_url}, service, operation, parameters) do
  url = "http://{camera-domain}:87362/onvif/ptz_service
  namespace = shorten_service(service)

  [username, password] = auth |> String.split(":")
  onvif_request = gen_onvif_request(namespace, operation, parameters) |> IO.inspect

  headers = [
    {"Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"},
    {"SOAPAction", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"}
  ]

  case Evercam.HTTP.post(url, headers, onvif_request, digest_auth: {username, password}) do
    {:ok, %Finch.Response{status: 404, body: body}} ->
      {:error, 404, %{body: body}}

    {:ok, response} ->
      {xml, _rest} = response.body |> to_charlist |> :xmerl_scan.string()

      soap_ns =
        case elem(xml, 3) do
          {ns, _} -> ns
          _ -> "env"
        end

      case response.status == 200 do
        true ->
          case "/#{soap_ns}:Envelope/#{soap_ns}:Body/#{namespace}:#{operation}Response"
               |> to_charlist
               |> :xmerl_xpath.string(xml) do
            [] ->
              {:error, 405,
               "/#{soap_ns}:Envelope/#{soap_ns}:Body"
               |> to_charlist
               |> :xmerl_xpath.string(xml)
               |> parse_elements}

            xpath_string ->
              {:ok, parse_elements(xpath_string)}
          end

        false ->
          "/html"
          |> to_charlist
          |> :xmerl_xpath.string(xml)
          |> parse_content(response, soap_ns, XML)
      end

    {:error, error} ->
      {:error, 500, Exception.message(error)}
  end
end
```

**OnVif Request Body**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis=200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <tptz:ContinuousMove xmlns:tptz="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl">
            <tptz:ProfileToken>Profile_1</tptz:ProfileToken>
            <tptz:Velocity>
                <!-- Move Left  -->
                <!-- <PanTilt x="-0.4" y="0.0" xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema"/> -->
                <!-- Move Right -->
                <PanTilt x="0.4" y="0.0" xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema"/>
            </tptz:Velocity>
        </tptz:ContinuousMove>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This code works for Hikvision cameras but for Milesight cameras it gives following error.

```
{:ok,
 %Finch.Response{
   status: 401,
   body: "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>401 Unauthorized</TITLE></HEAD>\n<BODY><H1>401 Unauthorized</H1>\nYour client does not have permission to get URL from this server.\n</BODY></HTML>\n",
   headers: [
     {"date", "Tue, 19 Mar 2024 10:04:03 GMT"},
     {"server", "WebServer"},
     {"connection", "close"},
     {"www-authenticate",
      "Digest qop=\"auth\", realm=\"IPNC\", nonce=\"a807934f7c0d0d3f689hf689nbfe21ba\", stale=\"FALSE\""},
     {"content-length", "164"},
     {"content-type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8"}
   ],
   trailers: []
 }}
```

When I use Postman to send OnVif requests with the same parameters and request body it works.